# What type of a chess player am I?

Tags: style

I'd like to know what sort of a chess player I am. Am I too much of an attacker, or a defender? Or maybe, a little bit of both? On the contrary, I enjoy attacking and deploying stealthy tactics but I'd like to know from you guys, what KIND of a player am I?

Here are two games from which you can tell my style. In the first one, I play as white and in the second, black. (Note that both of the opponents were defeated due to resignation)

[First]

http://en.lichess.org/TB2LHLZi#0

[Second]

http://en.lichess.org/TZGTdIyr#0

So there it is; now what do you think?

Comment: The 2nd game is a great example of why one should castle early.

Answer (score 4):

> Here are two games from which you can tell my style.

How could anyone judge something like this basing on **two** games? Imho those games aren't good examples at all. Those weren't any tactical, sharp games and not positional ones for sure. Your opponents just blundered. But you have taken adventage of it, so you're **perceptive**, that's good for you:) A bit offtopic: I'd suggest you to learn some openings, I've got a feeling that you don't have a solid repertoire.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell with only 2 games. But you seem to be a tactical player. You capitalized on tactical errors in both games.  Were the games against the same person? They felt like it.

Comment: Thanks for analyzing! And no, the games were against different opponents.